# Python: Timing of object creation in loop/comprehension/map vs. one-off

Tags: python, loops, object, timing

I am asking this generically since I can't post the actual code for various reasons.  The following is done in an iPython Notebook

I have created a class structured like this (it requires numpy)

```
class MyClassName(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.read_binary_file()      # Run these on object creation
        self.calculate_parameters()
        self.check_for_errors()

        ...
    def read_binary_file( self ):    # This requires numpy.
        #                            #      The file is 250MB binary and
        #                            #      ultimately yields a numpy array
        #                            #      32 x 32 x 100000 element
        ...
    def calculate_parameters( self ):
        ...
    def check_for_errors( self ):
        ...
    def other_function1( self ):
        ...
    def other_function2( self ):
```

etc.

The code is sound.  I can do the following

```
q = MyClassName('testfile.dat') # Instantiate an object
q.other_function1()             # Invoke methods
```

etc.

```
%timeit q = MyClassName('testfile.dat')
```

gives about 0.9 seconds for this creation

**But**, if I have a list of files
**`filenames = ['f1.dat', 'f2.dat', ..., 'f10.dat']`**
and create objects within a loop, comprehension, or map

```
Chomp = map( MyClassName, filenames )

Chomp = [ MyClassName(j) for j in filenames ]

Chomp = []
for j in filenames:
    Chomp.append( MyClassName(j) )
```

it takes over 3.5 seconds to create each object. The loop takes 3.5 secs/file x number of files to complete

***Things I've tried:***
I've looked up information on list creation, list append timings, memory management/assumptions, disabling/reenabling garbage collection after each object creation, etc.

I've also imported run cprofile on a single object creation.

All of these report about 3.5 seconds. cprofile says that a numpy binary read was taking 2.5 seconds of the 3.5 s to create a single object.  But, this same routine gets called when I create a single object outside of a loop or cprofile.

It is only the creation of a single object that goes quickly.

I am running on a Windows 7 machine and monitored the Task Manager.  At one point it looked like I had tapped out of physical memory and was page swapping so I rebooted, restarted iPython/Notebook, enabled only one kernel, and had few other programs running.  The memory load went down but the loop performance didn't get any better.

I'm new to OOP in general, been working with Python for a couple of months, and interested in understanding what's going on so I can code more appropriately.

Comment: I there a chance, that when you timed `%timeit q = MyClassName('testfile.dat')` the file was already cached in memory, because you accessed it before? That could yield much lower score.

Comment: I tried creating a bunch of files one at a time and each timed out at <1 second.  But, as I was doing a lot of experimenting, I can't be certain that they weren't in the cache from a prior test.  In fact, I didn't know that Python cached...  If they were in memory, wouldn't they be pulled from cache within the loop?

Comment: @OldGuyInTheClub: %timeit may run the function multiple times, which may give it a speedup on subsequent runs with the exact same inputs.  As opposed to  your loop where it has different input each time, hence no cache hits.

Comment: @OldGuyInTheClub you may want to profile during development and rather move outside of GUI-wrapped python for faster code-execution. The old-plain **`for`**-loop also allows for a more precise timing, if not making already an in-Class implemented `[usec]`-profiling reporting ( on grounds of 1-3 seconds, there is a lot space for a few nanoseconds overhead to be spent inside Class-methods to give your detailed code-execution times )

Comment: @John Zwinck: Ok, I will definitely look into this in the morning when I am back at work.  But, IIRC, running the object creation without the timeit took on the order of 1-sec.  I started timeits when I started running loops and got times which felt odd

Comment: @JohnZwinck You might have noticed, that this is the very case for the in-vitro production run of the code. Memory-access & gc artifacts in %timeit testing are confusing for these cases.

Comment: @user3666197 - Thank you.  By GUI-wrapped do you mean the iPython Notebook interface?  That's the only GUI I think applies here but I could be wrong.  This code will ultimately run in a Notebook since it analyzes instrument data in a lab and we use the Notebook as an informal documentation tool.

Comment: @OldGuyInTheClub If your Project architecture allows and the processing-task-phases are about the similar in time, there you may go multi-processed, with inter-process-communication used to avoid any "costly" memory-access/memory-copy overheads ( check the numpy in-RAM sizes ) and harness your multi-processor/multi-core ( multi-host if going into a privateCloud/Grid ) processing resources in parallel processing-pipeline orchestration.

Comment: @OldGuyInTheClub As asked, yes, iPython is a great rapid prototyping & trial/error-demonstrations'-frienly dev/UI environment, however the production-grade processing only "suffers" from overheads associated with the UI-frontend ( + sometimes low-level socket/stdio things collide "behind-curtain", as read from support forums on how to solve these internalites ). Going  from DEV / TEST into PROD / BAU the number-crunching performance & fail-safe operations' flow take primer ( well, in most reasonable motivated environments do ).

Answer (score 0):

[Answer converted from question]

---

**The Solution**

- There was no actual problem(!)... just very bad observations by me.

As m.wasowski and JohnZwinck pointed out in the comments, `%timeit` runs multiple times.  And as they said, subsequent runs artificially deflate the times due to caching.

Of all the things I tried, I did not try the following:

```
import time
tin = time.time()
q = MyClassName('testfile.dat')
print time.time() - tin
```

The first time I instantiate 'testfile.dat', it takes a full 3.3-3.5 seconds.
If I run that fragment again, it comes in at ~0.9seconds
So, timeit was taking the best of multiple runs as the commenters said

And I should know better than to have trusted my empirical observation of how long it took to instantiate an object manually.  The single object never did instantiate more quickly than the loop.

Thanks to all for the quick replies.